# How to POST jQuery variable through ajax to external PHP SQL script and return values

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to pass a jQuery variable (var datastring), that is a string, through ajax to the external drug_scripts.php file that echos out the value. I can get it to work if I set the data to a numerical value, however if I set it to the variable it returns NULL.

I've set data: ({dataSTring: dataString}) -- returns NULL.
Setting data: ({name: 123}) --- returns 123

AJAX:

```
 var dataString = '<?php print $DF_NAME1; ?>';

 $.ajax({
   url: "/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/assets/php/drug_scripts.php",
   type:"POST",
   dataType: 'json',
   data:  ({dataString: 125}),
   success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
   }
  });
```

PHP:

```
$userInput = $_POST['dataString'];

echo $userInput;
```

Again, the current state returns 123. If you were to set data to data: (dataString) it returns NULL.

Comment: That's because you need to post _both_ the key _and_ the value.  You just happen to be using the same name for the key and for the Javascript variable.

Comment: @PatrickQ Could you provide any example for this? I've changed the code to data: ({product: dataString}) and in the PHP i've set $_POST['product'];  --- This doesn't even return NULL.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis there and that should work just fine

Comment: Also, your ajax request is expecting a JSON response.  So depending on what the value is that you are echo-ing, there is a (good) chance that it is not valid JSON.

Comment: @PatrickQ it's still not returning anything. Again, this AJAX data: (dataString) and PHP $_POST['dataString'] returns NULL. Sorry for repeating, just want to try and be as clear as possible. The value of the string I'm trying to echo is 'ZOVIRAX - ACYCLOVIR SODIUM  (GENERIC)'

Comment: Yeah, that value definitely isn't valid JSON.  Also, why are you back to `data: (dataString)`?  You just said you changed it to `data: ({product: dataString}) `.  I'm afraid I can't really follow this anymore.

Comment: @PatrickQ I was just trying to get back to the point of anything returning.. Sorry for the back and forth. I've set it to data:({product: dataString}) and nothing is outputting with the value of 'ZOVIRAX - ACYCLOVIR SODIUM (GENERIC)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume `$DF_NAME1` is defined as something like `<?php $DF_NAME1 = 'name'; ?>` (which you will get somewhere, like the database)

Then:

```
<script>var dataString = "<?=$DF_NAME1?>";</script>
```

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {  
    var dataToSend = 'dataString=' + dataString;
     $.ajax({
       url: "/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/assets/php/drug_scripts.php",
       type:"POST",
       dataType: 'json',
       data:  dataToSend,
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
       }
      });
  });
</script>
```

The PHP file:

```
<?php
$userInput = $_POST['dataString'];
echo json_encode($userInput);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  both  ...  attribute name and attribute value

```
   ....
  type:"POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data:  ({attribute_name:'attribute_value'}),
  ....
```

in your case

```
  ....
  type:"POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data:  ({dataString : dataString }),
  ....
```

in `$_POST['dataString']` you should obtain  the content of the var `dataString`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works as I have rewritten the code for you.

In the script below, You can see that I just alert the **dataString** variable to see if it has any value. if the alert is empty, it means you are not passing any value to the datastring variable.

I have also tested it with variable data string set to **NancyMooree** which I commented

```
<html><head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 



<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    //var dataString = 'NancyMoore';    
var dataString = '<?php echo $DF_NAME1; ?>';

// check that datastring has value in it by alerting it
alert(dataString);
var datasend = "dataString ="+ dataString ;

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:'/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/assets/php/drug_scripts.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                 console.log(data);

                $('#listresult').fadeIn('slow').prepend(data);

            }


        });


});
</script>
  </head>
    <body>
    <div id="listresult"> </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**php**

```
<?php

$userInput = $_POST['dataString'];
echo $userInput;

?>
```